# Drawable image in GWT

Tags: gwt

I need to be able to draw lines on top of an Image in GWT. Anyone knowing about a way to do this?

BR

Niclas

Answer (score 1):

See the GWTCanvas project part of the GWT Incubator

[GWTCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/GWTCanvas)

You can draw images and then draw lines over the image on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

Create a simplePanel with height = 0px and the width you want, then assign it a style that say its border are black and have a size of 2px.